# MacBook Pro - Aquamacs - spell check

Tags: installation, macbook, spell-check, aquamacs, aspell

I have tried to use spell check for aquamac.

I highlighted a region of the text. Then clicked Edit, then spell check region. I got the error message:

> Error : No word lists can be found for the language "en_US".

Then I went to the [website](http://aquamacs.org/spelling.shtml) to download the following dictionaries:

1. CocoAspell : I just clicked the download button. It was reported that the download was successful. However, when I tested it and highlighted a text region and clicked spell check. The same error message came out.

   Do I need to pull the downloaded .pkg to a certain place, such as the application folder, before I opened the .pkg?

   Or what else do I need to do make it work?
2. I also downloaded the base package Aspell (for Intel) and the pre-built dictionaries as (as the instruction of the website), just the same way as point 1. I still got the same error message.

   Again, Do I need to pull the downloaded .pkg to a certain place, such as the application folder, before I opened the .pkg?

   Or what else do I need to do make it work?

I would be greatly appreciated if someone could give me some help?

Peggy Li

Comment: By the way, please accept answers to your old questions if they were answered. Everything here works off reputation points given by selecting the check mark next to answers. You can view old questions in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

You state you download the .pkg but did you go through the installation? Double-click on it and it should walk you through an installation process. You can test if aspell is installed by typing "aspell" on the command line in Terminal.app. Did you quit and restart Aquamacs after installing the spell checker?

Answer (score 0):

Also, you should be aware of the flyspell mode, which does spell checking on-the-fly.